# LaTeX Error: \begin{table*} on input line

Tags: formatting

The following code generates the error message

> "LaTeX Error: \begin{table*} on input line 69 by \end{table}

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{Variable assignment to blocks in the three-form design.}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        Rotation Block A & Rotation Block B & Rotation Block C \\
        \midrule
        CARINFO & SCINTACT & PERSCIE\\
        CARPREP & SCINVEST &  RESPDEV \\
        ENVAWARE & SCSCIE & SCAPPLY \\
        INSTSCIE  & ENVOPT &  SCHANDS \\
        JOYSCIE & ENVPERC & SCIEACT \\
        SCIEFUT & GENSCIE &  SCIEEFF \\
                & INTSCIE & \\        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

When I type set the whole document with this part commented out, it runs just fine.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Apart from design issues: Your table works for me, if copied into a small sample document that is compilable (which is actually your job to provide, not our job). Especially, I don't get a `table*` error message

Comment: You are right.  It works in a sample document.  But, not in my full document as I mentioned.  Not sure what the table* message is getting at, but that is the problem.

Comment: And sorry to have not supplied a compliable document.  I'm new to TeX.SE.

Comment: Are you including the booktabs psckage?

Comment: The example show  `\begin{table} .... \end{table}` that have nothing to do with the question title, and of course should  work, as well as   `\begin{table*} .... \end{table*},` but the error message say that you are using really  `\begin{table*} .... \end{table}` that of course is wrong. Otherwise you should clarify what are you doing really.

Comment: do you really get an error about `\begin{table*}` from input that does not have command that anywhere?

Comment: you can edit your question to add an example.

Comment: it sounds like you have a `\begin{table*}` that doesn't have a matching end command at all.  search in your file for `\begin{table*}`.  then search for the next instance of the string `{table` (important to have the opening brace *but no closing brace* in the search string).  my guess is that it will be `\begin{table}`, indicating that you've got an unclosed `table*` just like the error message says.  if your job has multiple files, the `\begin` and `\end` may not even be in the same file.

Comment: to make an example document do not try commenting out the part that you think makes an error. start from a copy of your document and delete everything that you can delete _checking at each stage the error still occurs_. when you finally get down to a document small enough to post post it. If you delete something  and the error goes, but it back, and delete something else.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: add an asterisk to `\end{table}` → → → `\end{table*}`

Any open environment should be closed by the same environment. Consider this nonsense non-working minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
asdasd  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This will produce the same type of error:

> LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 3  ended by \end{table}.

The same apply to starred versions.  Both `\begin{table*}` and `\begin{figure*}` are differents environments that `table` and `figure` and therefore should end with the correspondent `\end{table*}` and `\end{figure*}`, respectively.

Comment: If I compile the document with \begin{table*} and \end{table*}, I get the following error message:                                                "Runaway argument? ! File ended while scanning use of \efloat@xflot.

Comment: @David This is the `x-1` next error. Maybe because you are using endfloat? See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62278/problems-with-endfloat-package. Without construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` **that  reproduce  exactly that error**, find the  `x-1, x-2,...` errors of your  document could be a endless headache for you and an impossible mission for us.

Comment: @David: Please do as Fran asked you: Provide a compilable document