# Collect all figures at end with memoir

Tags: floats, memoir, endfloat

I've written a book with the memoir class (a great package, I take my hat off to the author), and I now need a version that has all the figures at the end (or the end of each chapter), each on a separate page together with the figure caption. This is the kind of thing that the endfloat package does, but when I try it I get *lots* of error messages and the compilation fails, so I wonder if the two packages are incompatible? (Neither package mentions the other in its documentation.) I also have lots of customizations for the figures and captions, for example putting the caption in the margin in a pseudo-Tufte style, which I think endfloat would have a hard time with even if they were compatible.

So my question is simply how to put all the figures at the end in a document using the memoir class? Thanks.

Comment: One approach is first to enclose your `\includefigure` within a newcommand (e.g. `\newcommand{\putfig}[1]{...}` and then use that new command either to put the figure directly or to ship out the figures to a separate file. Can you post a MWE that shows at least one case of including a figure so that a concrete example can be generated from it.

Comment: Please show us a short compilable code using class `memoir` and `endfloat` resulting in your issue(s).  If possible use `example-image` from package `mwe` ...

Comment: Be sure that you write every `\end{float}` at the start of a new line. Possible duplicate of [Problems with endfloat package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62278/problems-with-endfloat-package)?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. On further investigation it seems there is no incompatibility per se between endfloat and memoir. But because of the complex nature of my figures and captioning it doesn't always work well (so far).  Wrapping the figures in \newcommand{\putfig}{\begin{figure}...} requires quite a bit of manual labour but does at least work, so I can use that as a workaround,