# can't figure out where are Errors compilations in apa7 or apa6

Tags: compilation-error, apa7

I can't figure out where are the errors during the compilation in latex
here is a sample with my preambule.

```
 \documentclass[man]{apa7}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}

    \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
    \usepackage{caption,subcaption}
    \usepackage{algorithmicx}
    \usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

    \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\mid}{\mid}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf,skip=0.5\baselineskip,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
    \usepackage{pdfsync}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
    \newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[subsection]

    \addbibresource{distbib.bib}


    \title{Sample APA-Style Document Using the \textsf{apa7} Package}
    \author{Daniel A. Weiss}
    \affiliation{A University Somewhere}
    \leftheader{Weiss}
    \abstract{This demonstration paper uses the \textsf{apa7} \LaTeX\
    class to format the document in compliance with the 7th Edition of
    the American Psychological Assocation’s \textit{Publication Manual.}
    The references are managed using \textsf{biblatex}.}
    \keywords{APA style, demonstration}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    We begin with \textcite{Scha85}. We can also cite this work in
    parenthesis, like this: \parencite{Lam1}.
    A three-author paper \parencite[e.g.,][]{rao} lists all
    three authors for the first citation, then only the first author
    on all subsequent citations \parencite{rao}.
    Note the use of five heading levels throughout this demonstration
    Method section.
    %\input{chap2}
    \section{Method}
    \subsection{Participants}
    We had a lot of people in this study.
    \subsection{Materials}
    Several materials were used for this project. Some of them were
    already created for prior research.
    \subsubsection{Paper-and-Pencil Instrument}
    We used an instrument that we found to be highly successful.
    \paragraph{Reliability}
    The reliability of this instrument is extraordinary.
    \paragraph{Validity}
    We now discuss the validity of our instrument.
    \subparagraph{Face validity} The face validity is exceptionally
    \section{Discussion}
    This is a lengthy and erudite discussion. It demonstrates amazing
    skill in interpreting the results for the masses.
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You should load a package only once. Indeed you will get errors if you load a package several times with different options. In your preamble you load `biblatex` twice. Remove the second call `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}` (since it contains unnecessary options). With a modern TeX system (which you probably have if `apa7` is available) you won't need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`.

Comment: Other than that the code looks OK. I couldn't test the example exactly as posted, because I don't have your `distbib.bib`, but if I take `biblatex-examples.bib` and citations from that file, everything compiles for me. You should, however, still consider removing packages you don't need (or you don't know) from your preamble: The shorter the preamble, the smaller the risk for clashes and incompatibilities. I recommend to people to only load a package if you know why you load it.

Comment: If removing `biblatex` does not help, please show us the complete error message you get. (It would be even greater to see the full `.log`, but these are usually too long for inclusion in the question. You have to upload them to an external site: Please use a text-sharing site such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/ and **not** a file-sharing website such as Dropbox or Google Drive).

Comment: when i launched the compilation. it stops and this is the last thing appeared: ("C:\Users\Charriffaini\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfsync\pdf
sync.sty")
("C:\Users\Charriffaini\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l
3backend-pdfmode.def") (essayapa7.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.76 \abx@aux@

Comment: Delete the temporary files (`essayapa7.aux`, `essayapa7.bbl`, `essayapa7.bcf`, ...) and try again. (Of course you still need to make sure to only call `biblatex` once, as I wrote above.) If that doesn't help, please upload the complete `.log` file.

Comment: good the sample worked as i followed your advice thank you.  but now it blocks ; as i put all the subfiles together to create the final document , first thins appeared is this( i do not know how to upload the .log) (essayapa7.fff))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \efloat@xfloat.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.57 \input{chap2}

Comment: We need to see code that reproduces this error (if the example above does not reproduce it, try to add enough code to make it show the error). To upload the `.log` just open the `.log` file with your favourite text editor, copy all its contents and paste it to https://pastebin.com/.

Comment: i post the file .log in: https://pastebin.com/u/Chamanga

Comment: probably unrelated but you should update your tex system you have latex 2020-02-02 but there were 5 patch releases to that. Your log shows no error but it is terminated mid line which suggests that when you got an error you killed the process from the operating system rather than let tex quit cleanly. But as you have not provided an example that produces the problem and the log shows no error, it is hard to give definite help. Try to may a small example that shows the problem and add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that does not appear to be the complete `.log` file. It stops abruptly in the middle of a line with `Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'nam`. Note also that the `.log` file is only really useful *together* with a short example document that reproduces the error.

Comment: ok, i post another where I click "x" to leave. https://pastebin.com/KYeBL6Nw

Comment: I googled the error message and found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62278/35864. But other than that I will unfortunately not be able to help you without seeing the code that reproduces the error. Take a copy of your `essayapa7.tex` and remove as much as you can. The error quite probably comes from a `figure` or `table` environment. Check for those first.